# Setting up resources in separate dll WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly, resourcedictionary

I am wanting to have a set of styles contained within a standalone dll that can be referenced from a number of different WOF classes to define common styles.

I have created the standalone dll and tried referencing it but am having problems.

Here is the code for the standalone dll:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

        <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
        </Style>

    <!-- store here your styles -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is where Im trying to reference it:

```
<src:GX3ClientPlugin.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GX3StyleResources.dll;component/GX3StyleResources.xaml" />
</src:GX3ClientPlugin.Resources>
```

When running I get the following exception:

> *Could not load file or assembly 'GX3StyleResources.dll, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.*

Any Ideas?

Comment: From my experience, it is hard to manage if you keep resources, images, etc in differet project. I also think that it has very little benefit if not none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do the same in some of my projects, what I do is to add the dll as a Reference into my project, then I use the pack Uri but i don't specify the extension .dll. I just use the assembly name (usually withouth .dll)

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/GX3StyleResources;component/GX3StyleResources.xaml"
```

Comment: The problem was that I had .dll on the end of the assembly name.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before as well. If you never actually reference anything in that assembly in actual C# code, sometimes (the criteria for which I cannot for the life of me determine) the compiler / the runtime / some combination of both just doesn't load or copy your assembly.

Add a class to your resource assembly file that does SOMETHING / anything - don't leave it blank, otherwise it will get optimized away in some cases:

```
public static class Resources
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        Console.Write(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Then, from your application, call Resources.Init() in your App startup method before anything else to ensure the resource assembly gets loaded.

It's a dirty dirty hack, but it works.